# Having trouble installing Autotest in Rails in Ubuntu 10.10 enviroment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm learning how to program in Rails. I'm a complete newbie, and I'm learning from the screen-cast "Rails Tutorial: Learn by Example" by Michael Hartl.

I've been doing pretty well, until I've come to this obstacle, and I don't know how to figure it out. It's a bit frustrating to be frank, and I'd like to move forward with Rails & start making stuff :)

I installed RubyGems 1.8.5 by hitting:

```
$ gem update --system
```

and then installed ZenTest gem by hitting:

```
$ sudo gem install ZenTest
```

then I installed auto-test rails gem by hitting:

```
$ sudo gem install autotest-rails
```

and so got the message

```
Successfully installed autotest-rails-4.1.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for autotest-rails-4.1.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for autotest-rails-4.1.0...
```

So all was lookin' fine and dandy. I navigated to my app folder, and hit

```
$ autotest
```

and then got the message

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem ZenTest (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:219:in `activate'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1065:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/autotest:18:in `<main>'
```

I've tried searching for an answer to why this is happening, but I can't find any. Please help me solve this problem. I'd like to move forward with learning Rails :)

*EDIT* Maybe I should also mention that I have RSpec installed already -- I don't know if that's of any significance -- giving you a better understanding as to whats going on with my problem -- but I thought I'd just put it out there.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Rails 3+? If so look for a file called Gemfile inside the rails app root directory. Open it up, add:

```
gem 'ZenTest'
gem 'autotest-rails'
```

Save, exit and then run from command line:

```
bundle
```

After this try rerunning autotest

Comment: OK that worked. I don't know why I didn't just do it the bundle way, as I have been doing with my other gems. Part of the learning process I guess. I really appreciate the help man. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm at the same point of learning RoR (in this case RoR 3.0.3, Ruby 1.9.2p180, Ubuntu 11.04). I'm also stymied by the lack of consistency. In my case:

```
$ "You don't have i18n installed in my application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle  install".

Gemfile:
gem 'ZenTest'
gem 'autotest-rails'
gem 'i18n'

$bundle install => OK
$bundle show i18n => <ruby path>/gems/i18n-0.6.0
$autotest => (same result)
```

Any ideas? This is NOT going to help RoR adoption, if it's so obtuse to load a basic TDD environment. (I'll step off my soapbox now.)

Answer (score 0):

try in command line "bundle install"